# Salesforce data design tool

Tags: master-detail, data-designer

I am looking for design tool to draw salesforce data design. I have tried Power Point and Visio but I like this design:

[image]

Comment: You have the schema builder directly inside Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I am looking something other than schema builder. I need an end design something like the picture in the post above.

Comment: I like [Cacoo](https://cacoo.com). But if you want to automatize this you should try to synchronize data between Salesforce and Heroku using: [Heroku Connect](https://www.heroku.com/connect). With Heroku Connect, you could have a postgres database linked to your Salesforce data. And then, you could use a tool to generate the diagram like [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but there are a couple of other tools that I know of that will allow you to easily draw your own Entity Relationship Diagrams as well as UML Diagrams that work fairly well.

The first, is the one that I use, it's called [Lucid Charts](http://www.lucidchart.com) and runs in your browser. It has pre-configured styles and will automatically connect your shapes for you while allowing you to change the line style and type of connections at each end, plus many other features. It does a variety of style ERD, UML and process diagrams, plus much more. Note that Lucid Charts is a subscription service.

One that can be purchased through BitsDuJour is called [DbSchema: Database Digagram Designer](http://www.bitsdujour.com/software/dbschema/in=search-for-software). However, it only does ERD diagrams, but it also has utilities to help with query designs.

The last tool I can think of (not subscription) is [EDraw Max](https://www.edrawsoft.com/edraw-max.php). It also creates nice ERD and UML diagrams plus much more.

Beyond those, you'd be looking at Adobe Illustrator or Corel Draw which aren't going to be intuitive or easy to use for these kinds of purposes.

If you want to map class relationships, Andy Fawcett's UML Canvas tool on Github will help facilitate doing that for you if you install it in your org.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://dbdesigner.net.
Its free and you can design SF based data models.

Its very basics but far more faster and efficient than Schema builder. 
 [image]